# How to make a safe file function in PHP?

Tags: php

This method receives a foldername and filename. It should make sure that the filename actually really exists in the folder path before doing anything. If so then it can proceed to get the file, send headers and send the response content. Is there a better and more secure way to to do this?

```
 public function is_file_in_path($filename, $filepath)
 {
        if (file_exists($filepath)) {
            $filename = realpath($filepath);
        }
        if ($filename) {
            $image_mime = get_mime_by_extension($filename);
            header('Content-Type: ' . $image_mime);
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
            echo file_get_contents($filename);
        } else {
            show_error('No image found.', 404);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Does your code work? If so, this question is off-topic for StackOverflow. If you are looking for a review of your code, try the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) website. Code looks fine to me though.

Comment: Having an optional first parameter seems a bit odd.

Comment: There's a function called "Is file in path?" that generates an HTTP response. I find that confusing. It's like writing a function to calculate an average and call it `shut_down()`.

Answer (score 0):

To make the function to have higher compatibility and cleaner:

1. consider removing the word "public"
2. remove the 1st parameter, which is a bit redundant
3. change get_mime_by_extension to mime_content_type
4. change "No image found" to "No File found" (because this function can also be used if you supply a PDF file as parameter).

```
<?php

function is_file_in_path($filepath)
 {
 if (file_exists($filepath)) {
            $filename = realpath($filepath);
        }

        if ($filename) {

        $file_mime = mime_content_type($filename);

        header('Content-Type: ' . $file_mime);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
        echo file_get_contents($filename);

            
            
            } else {
//           show_error('No image found.', 404);
            echo "No File Found";
        }}
  
//  is_file_in_path("./photo.jpg");

is_file_in_path("./ess.pdf");

  
  ?>
```